# JavaScript: обнаружить пропуск строки в textarea

Tags: javascript

Как с помощью `JavaScript` (если будет проще - то и с подключением`jQuery`) обнаружить пропуск строки в `<textarea>`?

Поясню задачу: нужно, обрабатывая введённые данные в `<textarea>`, все абзацы, разделяемые пропуском строки, обернуть в `<p>`. Не нужно приводить полное решение, просто подскажите пожалуйста принцип, принимая во внимание то, как я дальше буду использовать полученное знание.

Comment: А зачем оборачивать в р??? Может подскажем другое решение?

Comment: Как зачем? Всё же в один абзац отобразится, сколько пустых строк не вставляйте в исходный текст между абзацами.

Comment: Текст введенный в браузере в textarea вы где обрабатываете? В браузере на javascript (и что дальше с ним делаете?) или на сервере (на каком языке программирования?)?

Comment: Конкретно в моём случае удобнее обработать текст с помощью `Javascript` (включая `jQeury`). По отпусканию клавиши текст тут же обрабатывается, валидный HTML-код добавляется в отдельное поле и отображается (как на этом сайте при вводе вопроса или в jsfiddle). При нажатии кнопки "сохранить" в БД отправляется уже полностью сформированный после последнего ввода с клавиатуры валидный HTML-код.

Comment: CSS `white-space: pre-wrap;` отображает пробелы и пустые строки как есть, если что.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример. `jquery` используется только для получения DOM-объектов по селекторам, так что вы его можете не использовать.

```js
$('textarea').keyup(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    var p = function(s) { return '<p>' + s + '</p>'; }
  
    var content = val
        .split('\n\n') // разбиваем значение textarea на массив по двум переносам
        .map(function(item) { return p(item); }) // оборачиваем каждый элемент в тег p
        .join('') // получаем из элементов массива строку
        .replace(/\n/g, '<br>'); // заменяем оставшиеся переносы на <br>
  
    // console.log(content);
    $('#result').html(content);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea rows="5" cols="45"></textarea>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Отличное решение! Благодарю Вас за комментарии, благодаря которым я смог легко понять смысл кода!

Answer (score 2):

Вот пример:

```js
var text = '';
var area = document.getElementById('text');
var review = document.getElementById('review');
area.onkeyup = function() {
  var newtext = area.value;
  if (newtext != text) {
    text = newtext;
    newtext = newtext.replace(/</g, '&lt;')
                .replace(/>/g, '&gt;')
                .replace(/\n/g, '</p><p>')
                .replace(/(<p><\/p>)+/g, '<br>');
    review.innerHTML = '<p>' + newtext + '</p>';
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="post">
  <textarea id="text" rows="5" cols="45" name="text"></textarea>
</form>
<div id="review"></div>
```

В нем экранирую только символы `<` и `>`, хотя стоит еще и `"`, `'`, `&` экранировать наверное.

Comment: Благодраю Вас за решение! Очень элегантная функция. К сожалению, она оборачивает в новый p текст, перенесённый на новую строку, но не текст, идущий после пустой строки. Пока ещё не разобрался до конца в Вашем замечательном коде, но вероятно, его можно легко исправить до желаемого результата, если искать не перенос на новую строку, а два переноса на новую строку.